# ckeditor copy to clipboard behave different in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am copying text from Ckeditor. I have some custom tags which are displayed in CKEditor. When I am copying from ckeditor in firefox content is copied as html formatted(when pasted in editor html formatted text is pasted),my custom tags are not copied. But in chrome and IE my custom tags are copied and when I paste in editor custom tags are also pasted.

Can any one explain Why this is Happening and how to resolve this for Firefox.